# Display vimeo in fancybox , trouble in IE

Tags: fancybox, vimeo

i have a problem with VIMEO video .

I want to display it in fancybox :

this is HTML :

```
<a href="#content" class="zoom">test</a>

<div id="content" style="display:none;">


    <object width="504" height="280" data="http://vimeo.com/moogaloop.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash">
        <param value="always" name="allowscriptaccess"><param value="true" name="allowfullscreen">
        <param value="http://vimeo.com/moogaloop.swf" name="movie">
        <param value="clip_id=6999704&amp;server=vimeo.com&amp;fullscreen=1&amp;show_title=1&amp;show_byline=1&amp;show_portrait=1&amp;color=00ADEF" name="flashvars">
    </object>

</div>
```

and js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("a.zoom").fancybox();
    });
```

Can somebody help me with this , maybe somebody knows hot to fix it ..

Thanks !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this html:

```
<a href="#content" class="zoom">test</a>

<div style="display:none;">
<div id="content">


    <object width="504" height="280" data="http://vimeo.com/moogaloop.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash">
        <param value="always" name="allowscriptaccess"><param value="true" name="allowfullscreen">
        <param value="http://vimeo.com/moogaloop.swf" name="movie">
        <param value="clip_id=6999704&amp;server=vimeo.com&amp;fullscreen=1&amp;show_title=1&amp;show_byline=1&amp;show_portrait=1&amp;color=00ADEF" name="flashvars">
    </object>

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: yes it works, just for new version, but I was using 1.2.6 one, and even it didn't help me .. Thanks man for this !!